# Dialog Helper class

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I would like to ask for advice here, I want to create a dialog for a sign out box, because this box can be called from almost every screen, I want to create a new class which include this method and the call it every time the button is clicked, but honestly I don't know how to do it, I've created a class called SignOutHelper

```
public class SignOutHelper extends Activity {

public Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("do you wish to sign out?");
    builder.setTitle("Sign Out");

    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();   
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

now I want to call this class from a normal activity but I don't know how to do it, I'll appreciate your help thanks

Comment: a Dialog? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: looks like that is what i need, do you know if I can create a contact form as well with dialogs?

Comment: @Juanca diy johndiy yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

As some suggested you can create a `Dialog`, yet I personally would consider regular `Activity` **themed** the way it looks like popup (as I assume this is what you look for) i.e.:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like an option but don't really know how it works? is it the same as a Dialog?

Comment: No, it's normal activity (from code stand point) but it just **looks** like dialog (so it does not cover while screen, you see previous one underneath) etc. Test yourself: open one activity (normal) then open from it one with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"` and see

Comment: Thanks I tried and it works like I need, thanks for help!

Comment: If that answers your question, please approve the answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235